# Modification of a local martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I am quite curious to know if the following is true, which comes up to my mind when reading a paper on SLE:

For any local martingale $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and stopping time $\tau$, is it true that
$$ \big( X_t \mathbf{1}_ { \{t < \tau \} } + X_{\tau} \mathbf{1}_ { \{t \geq \tau \} } \big)_{t \geq 0}$$
is also a local martingale? The paper seems to use this fact implicitly.

But I don't really know how to handle the term $\mathbf{1}_ { \{{\tau_n} \wedge t  < \tau \} }$, where $\{\tau_n \}$ is a reducing sequence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X_{t \wedge \tau} 1_{t < \tau} = X_t 1_{t < \tau}$ and $X_{t \wedge \tau} 1_{t \geq \tau} = X_\tau 1_{t \geq \tau}$. Thus the sum you quote is simply an expansion of $X_{t \wedge \tau}$ which certainly is another local martingale.